# mqprio qdisc not working

Tags: traffic

I am using ubuntu 4.15.0-43-generic, I am trying to run the `mqprio qdisc` with this command

```
# tc qdisc replace dev ens4 handle 100: parent root mqprio num_tc 3 \
     map 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 queues 1@0 1@1 2@2 hw 0
```

but it gives me the error

> RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

could you suggest me the solution for this?

Comment: thanks Mr Shunz for formatting it well. I hope, will get the answer of my question soon.

Answer (score 1):

your tc command is correct, the problem is most likely caused by the network adapter.

mqprio to work requires a network adapter supporting multiple hardware queues
you may list network queues by issuing the command

```
ls /sys/class/net/<adapter name>/queues
```

additionally if your NIC support multiple queues, you can usually adjust the number of RX queues (also called RX channels), by using ethtool, see https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/#check-the-number-of-rx-queues-being-used